# Bifurcation of underdetermined dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm analyzing a dynamical system of three ODE's $\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z}$.

I'm interested in doing a bifurcation analysis of $\dot{x},\dot{y}-\dot{z}$. This is an underdetermined system of equations, and my google search on the subject brings only a few hits, so I'm in dire need of ideas to approaching this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Providing the expressions for these ODEs could be helpful.

Comment: I'm writing on a project, so I'm not sure I'm allowed to get that explicit kind of help. But can you help me with the general idea? I first considered defining a fourth variable $\dot{a} := \dot{y}-\dot{z}$, and then consider a poincare map in the $\dot{x}\dot{a}$-plane in the four dimensional phase space, but this really can't be done, when $\dot{a}$ is defined in this way - obviously(I said to myself after trying).

Comment: Sorry to insist, but it is impossible to do a bifurcation analysis of "an underdetermined system of equations".